# Setting Multiple Variables to Result of Query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I have the query below, that will return the city and state that is the shortest distance between an inputted set of points and all rows of the table `Metros`:

```
@lat = row[latitude]
@long = row[longitude]

Metros.select(
        "major_city
        , major_state
        ,(latitude - " + @lat + ")**2 + (longitude - " + @long + ")**2 as 'distance'")
           .group("major_city,major_state").limit(1).order('distance ASC')
```

What I need to do now is set the result to two variables `row[major_city]` and `row[major_state]` with `major_city` set to `row[major_city]` and `major_state` to `row[major_state]`.

How can I accomplish this task two allow for setting to the two variables independently?

Answer (score -1):

It comes out with a ActiveRecord::Relation type even if it was just one piece of result, so use .first and then take it as a single record may work.

Comment: What do you mean take it as a single record? Could you provide an example?

Comment: Your 'select' blabla thing comes out for a data type like an array, just set a example by result= [{:a=>1,:b=>2, :c=>3}], you can't set what you want by row[major_city] = result.a, is that your problem? If so, change is to result.first.a .

Comment: So could I set the result of the query to a an array as it would return something like `@result = [New York City, NY]` and I would simply set `@majoy_city = @result[0]` and `@major_state = @result[1]`?

Comment: No, I think it should be like:`@majoy_city = @result[0].majoy_city and @major_state = @result.majoy_state`, Am I make myself clear?